# SQL: using a field as another field using where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a database:

```
DRN | VoucherNo | CrDRN
-----------------------    
1   |80        |?
2   |11        |?
3   |11        |?
4   |80        |?
5   |11        |?
```

I'm trying to get the `DRN` number for the `CrDRN` column.

It is calculated like this:

- The `CrDRN` of every row with the voucher type will be its `DRN` number
- Any row with the `VoucherType` of 11 will have the `DRN` number of the previous record where the `VoucherType` equals 80

So in this instance the `CrDRN` column values will be:

```
1
1
1
5
5
```

I was thinking I'd need to use a `Where VoucherType = 80`

But I can't wrap my head around the concept of the second 80

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you define "previous record"?

Comment: This sounds dangerous - I would strongly advise you redesign this table so no  row's values are dependent on other rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this logic using a correlated subquery, assuming that "previous" is based on the `drn` column:

```
select drn, voucherno,
       (case when voucherno <> 0 then t.drn
             else (select t2.drn
                   from table t2
                   where t2.id < t.id and
                         t2.voucherno = 80
                   order by t2.drn desc
                   limit 1
                  )
        end) as crDRN
from table t;
```

Comment: All of this is stored in one table. And yes, essentially this is to see which of the records that have 11 belong to which records above them that have a vouchertype of 80.  Basically like a deposit slip had a number of cheques that belong to it, this is how the system would know that these cheques belong to that deposit slip